# Adding attributed text to UITextView directly in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode5, uistoryboard, nsattributedstring, xcode-storyboard

I would like to place attributed text directly into a UITextView in the UITextView's setAttributedText field in the Attributes Explorer of my storyboard in Xcode 5.  I was hoping to avoid creating the NSAttributedString programmatically because this text will need to be localized and I would like to use the storyboard localization.

If it's not possible, I can create it manually in the UIViewController.  But I was hoping to do this directly to save a little coding.

Anyone know how to do this (assuming it's possible)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the option that you are looking for. After selecting "Attributed", you can paste anything you want below.

[image]

[image: this]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Ok, you are saying that to get attributed text into the UITextView I can't type it in directly but I need to type my text into another application such as Pages and format the text the way I want it to look. Then paste that into the UITextView. Do I have it correct?

Comment: Your welcome! If you paste it it will definitely work. I have done it a lot of times.

Comment: It worked great.  That you very much this saves me a lot of work.